# Low voltage to drive LED flash (not successful in simulation, but works on breadboard)

Tags: led, multisim, low-voltage

I first did this circuit on a breadboard, except I originally used a light-sensitive resistor, which is around 1 kΩ at daytime and above 160 kΩ in darkness.

It oscillates with LED as capacitor adds up to power source to offer higher voltage than what is needed to kick the red LED on.

In MS, since there is no light-sensitive resistance, the light-sensitive resistor was changed to 300 kΩ variable resistance, and firstly it was dragged to 0-5%, then I clicked "simulate" so as to have the capacitor charged to around 1.5 V, then I increased the variable resistance to 80%-100% to kick Q1 out of off-state status, but it did not oscillate.

[image]

Simulation not working.

[image]

On the breadboard it works.

---

[image]

I tried a lot of ways, and inspired by some others I modified this model on IS (transport saturation current to 1 e-009), and then it starts to oscillate. Does anyone know how it affects this circuit in detail?

Comment: C1 is not consistently the same value.

Comment: What is the LED forward voltage?

Comment: Most simulators need a 'kick' for an oscillator to start running.

Comment: Does the scope need to be connected to gnd?

Comment: @Audioguru,  how to fire this "kick"? any idea?

Comment: @Lundin, forward voltage is 1.5, it does not change or oscillate.

Comment: @PStechPaul, yes it has to be gnd since it is a simulation circuit. otherwise the system would alert me on this.

Comment: Let me put it this way: do you know the meaning of the term _diode forward voltage_? If a diode has larger forward voltage than the voltage supplied to its anode, it will not conduct. Usually LED have quite high forward voltages.